# Loading resources?

Tags: eclipse, resources, jaxb, classpath, loading

I'm sure this is a silly question, but I've tried a multitude of things and I just can't seem to get it. Here is what I have.

I have a project in eclipse. The structure is as follows.

/main/java (designated src folder)
/test/java (designated src folder)
/test/resources

in the /test/java branch I have all of my JUnits which, of course, test the classes found in the /main/java. The resources folder is used to store items that I need for my unit tests. I'm working with JAXB, so it contains sample XSD and XML files. Right now I have one file in there..

/test/resources/schema/sample.xsd

Now, I have created a class with a main method that instantiates a class, and then executes the only method. I am trying to do:

URL xsdFile = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "/resources/schema/sample.xsd");

but I am getting null as a returned value. I've also tried /schema/sample.xsd, but no luck there either. I'm modified the project build settings ensuring that /test/resources/schema is in the build path, but still no joy. When I run the main class (from within eclipse), it just can't pick up the file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make resources as a source folder (Right click-> Build Path-> Use as source folder) and use ...getResource( "schema/sample.xsd");

Comment: That worked (THANK YOU!). I was looking at other projects where people are able to reference it off the root /schema/sample.xsd. Any idea how I would get it to work that way (just out of curiosity)

Comment: You need to see how they have set the build path. They might have configured it that way